# How to move files in folder in Javascripts

Tags: javascript, file-upload, move

How can I move the uploaded preview file into another folder using js.
Here is snippet:

http://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/t6UP5/

```
refer above snippet
```

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded file cannot be moved to folders. Your implementation takes the image, encodes that as base64 and draws that directly on the page as inline resource. Since there is no backend service / server that handles the file upload, you won't be able to have something like a filesystem. It works all offline.

Comment: Its fine if its working offline, but can you guide me how can I achieve this even in offline
?